# Thompson's group T

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Does there exist a non trivial homomorphism from Thompson's group T to a linear group?

Comment: ... where a "linear group" is a group of automorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space, or over a finitely generated module? $\:$ In the latter case, what if any, are the restrictions on the ring of scalars? $\;\;\;$

Comment: By a linear group, I mean $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.


Comment: Actually, instead of ${\mathbb R}$, you can use any field. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No: T is infinite, finitely presented and simple.  Fg linear groups are residually finite, by Mal'cev's theorem. QED.